# changing ssas aggregation on decile column in fact table

Tags: ssas, cube

I have a FactPerson table, and within it I have a couple of decile columns and a PersonCount column. By default they have the sum aggregation assigned to it. With PersonCount the sum aggregation is correct, but i don't want the sum aggregation assigned to the decile column. I rather want to see the decile number and the personCount in that decile within the ssas browser.

Anyone know how to do that?

NOTE: I tried editing the decile column and changed it to no aggregation but it gives me a null back when I call it forward in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking Multidimensional not Tabular, build a dimension off the FactPerson table and make the deciles dimension attributes only, not measures.